# In the Dresden Books, is there any quantified hierarchy among the Sidhe Court political structure?

Tags: names, the-dresden-files

I don't know of any spoiler tags to hide things, so I'll be vague: it's recently become more relevant where the Summer/Winter Queens, Ladies, Knights sit.
So in terms of power: how does, say, the ‘Summer Lady' sit in power versus the ‘Winter Knight'?  And can a variance in one's internal ‘talents' rise above another's station?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The relative power levels of the queens is repeatedly stated by Harry, especially in the Cold Days novel.

It seems that everything else is the opinion of Harry, which is to be expected as it's written in the first person. Harry often feels the power of someone who is much more powerful than him, and can easily tell if someone is considerably less powerful.

Up to Cold Days the least of the Sidhe queens have always been more powerful than Harry. Now that he has the mantle of the Winter Knight he seems to be much closer in power to the lesser queens although still not nearly as powerful.

> The epic battle at the end of Cold Days shows Harry being outclassed by both Lily and Maeve, even though it is hinted that the mantle of the Winter Knight gives Harry a 'privileged' status against them.

In addition the power of an individual can increase in the Dresden Files universe. Harry has steadily increased in power over the course of the novels as have other characters. 
However given all that we can still deduce a rough set of power levels from Harry's point of view:

- Ultimate: Mothers, Gods
- Godlike: Queens, Vaderung
- Mighty: The Summer and Winter Ladies, Dragons, the Fallen, Outsiders
- Harry-like: Wizards, Knights
- Lesser: Paranet talents, Apprentices, etc

Comment: This answer half-true: the hierarchie of the quenns is correct, not their power level.

Comment: This is fairly close.  I was keying in on Ladies vs Knights based on where series was left after Cold Days, the potential dynamic between Harry and [new Summer Lady person] and [new Winter Lady person].

Comment: Revised power levels for nitpickers

Comment: To be fair, at the point in that spoiler, Harry is in traditional "Dresden, that Wily Genius" mode, he's not at his best.

Answer (score 2):

A basic answer:

Mother > Queen > Lady

And there is a huge gap in power between each one.

Mother: no idea if there is anything that can stop them.

Queens: Dragons, entire White Council.

Lady: very, very powerful wizard.

The comparison between Knight and Lady is not obvious. They are not very far from each other, but it seems that, based on Summer Knight and Cold Days, that the Lady is slightly more powerful than the Knight.

Comment: Considering he was killed by Michael by himself, I'd put the dragon Siriothrax at Lady level. On the other hand, we don't know how strong Ferrovax is, he might match a queen.

Comment: Archangels, having the "power to unmake galaxies", should match the mothers in power. Some of the old gods (mostly sleeping or imprisoned) might do so as well, but we have too little information to be sure.